# Change UITableViewCell's properties from the presented view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In a `UITableViewCell` on a button click, I do

```swift
EditPostViewController.type = "post"
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "editPost") as! EditPostViewController
top?.present(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

To go to EditPostViewController.
Now in this EditPostViewController, I have a textbox, the user edits and the clicks the back button.

How can I edit the variables of that particular `UITableViewCell` from  `EditPostViewController` after some button click event?

So I tried taking the variable of `self` in the UITableViewCell and then editing it in the EditPostViewController like

```swift
EditPostViewController.instance = self
```

And in `EditPostViewController`

```swift
EditPostViewController.instance.label.text = "something"
```

This doesn't work. This says that UITableViewCell has no property named instance. Any idea how can I edit the value of this label in the UITableViewCell from EditPostViewController?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at unwind segues to solve your problem (there are other ways as well).

The iOS developer jump right in page found here can show you detailed instructions on how to get it going:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementEditAndDeleteBehavior.html

Basically what you need to do is obtain the target view controller from the EditPostViewController during the unwind segue and update it's datsource. The unwind segue is an @IBAction defined on the "Back" button of the EditPostViewController (or any other button for that matter).